# What is the effect of image resize and configuration last dense layers on performance of transfer learning (VGG, ResNet) for classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build  a Spam classification model using the `tf2.0` and `Keras` for a project. It has to be very good model and I want to improve the accuracy of the model. Spam images can be any Image in the world except a handwritten question or a picture of a question like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xEE88WW5Gl4EZz9ZhVbLogCppy9ZMI7T/view?usp=sharing), or [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10M9pHB4k6qhhtwhb01MOw9DdxrM-MJAw/view?usp=sharing). I have almost 300000 images of each category so I want to retrain the model from random weights  because question images were not included in the imagenet data and I have enough data. **Please suggest if I should use the `imagenet` weights instead**. I want to improve the performance of my model. I have a model something like this:

```
res_net = ResNet50(include_top=False,weights=None,input_shape=(224,224,3)) # will try VGG and other models too if needed

av1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(res_net.output)

fc1 = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(av1)
fc2 = Dense(512,activation='relu')(fc1)
fc3 = Dense(256,activation='relu')(fc2)
d1 = Dropout(0.5)(fc3)

fc4 = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(d1)

model = Model(inputs=res_net.input, outputs= fc4)
```

**Qusetions**:

My images are question images and width is larger than height in most cases, so do I resize all images to (224,224) or to the `min(width or height)` in the whole data set (But that can suppress the details for larger images)?

I know the use of Dense layers are upto me but I can't use every possible combination of `units` and `number of layers` because of the obvious time, memory,power constraints. So If I use many dense layers / units, won't I be over-fitting my model as there are already many layers in these gigantic architectures?

Should I be using 3 channels or 1? Question images are mostly black with white backgrounds so it'll make training fast but 3 channels can have better results IMO??

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom architecture, you can have any dimension as you wish. But for already built architecture, image dimension is fixed. In Keras, you can visit each model from [Keras application link](https://keras.io/api/applications/#:%7E:text=Keras%20Applications%20are%20deep%20learning,They%20are%20stored%20at%20%7E%2F.) to check the required dimensions.

Dense layer are up to you. If you choose the number of neurons bigger, then the model may not fit into your GPU. Or if you choose the number of neurons too small, the learning would not be much accurate. However, if you are using an already built model, two or three fully connected layers are fine.

If you are using pre-trained weights from imagenet, you should choose 3 channels, otherwise, one can be used. But I would say go for three and take advantage of transfer learning. Though you have a lot of data, still using imagenet weights are good. Go for transfer learning, retrained them again, instead of fine-tuning.